# How to to globally disable E501 in VSCODE and pylama

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code and pylama linter.

Currently I am added `# noqa` to every long line to avoid the following linter message:

`line too long (100 > 79 characters) [pycodestyle]pylama(E501)`

I've added `"--disable=E501"` to VSCODE's workspace `settings.json` file as shown below:

```
{
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylamaEnabled": true,
   
    "[python]": {
      "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "python.linting.pylama": [
      "--disable=E501"
    ]    
}
```

but still I get E501.

How can I disable E501 in my VSCODE workspace for good?

Comment: Try `python.linting.pylamaArgs` as that would conform to how pylint args are specified.

Comment: @JonSG, that fixed the issue. Thank you!. The correct setting is     "python.linting.pylamaArgs": [
      "--ignore E501"
    ]  .

Comment: @JonSG, please create an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For other linters, the .settings file seems to be looking for

`python.linting.<linter>Args`

so I recommend trying:

```
"python.linting.pylamaArgs": [
  "--ignore=E501"
]
```

or potentially

```
python.linting.pylamaArgs": ["--disable=E501"]
```

See also: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_pylama

that seems to suggest the same:

```
pylamaArgs  []  Additional arguments for pylama, where each top-level element that's separated by a space is a separate item in the list.
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
I tried: 
    "python.linting.pylamaArgs": [
        "--ignore=E501",
        "--disable=E501",
        "--max-line-length=100",],
in the settings.json but nothing changed !

Comment: Try `python.linting.pylama`